# Show the smallest digit from three digits in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, min

I want to make a program in which user enter the three digits separated by the space and i want to show the smallest digit.

See my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
   int a,b,c;
   cout<<" enter three numbers separated by space... "<<endl;               
   cin>>a>>b>>c;
   int result=1;

   while(a && b && c){
           result++;
           a--; b--; c--;
           }
   cout<<" minimum number is "<<result<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Sample input:

3 7 1

Sample output:

2

It doesn't show the smallest digit. What's the problem in my code and how can I solve my problem?

Comment: You need to debug your code

Answer (score 4):

The result should be initialized by zero

```
int result = 0;
```

nevertheless the approach is wrong because the user can enter negative values.

The program could be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Enter three numbers separated by spaces: ";

    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    std::cout << "The minimum number is " << std::min( { a, b, c } ) << std::endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a hidden assumption here that `a`, `b` and `c` are positive. If you allow for such assumption, you're nearly there - you just need to initialize `result` to `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

hint:

When writing c++ always prefer to write code in terms of the algorithms that have been thoughtfully provided for you in the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int a,b,c;
    cout<<" enter three numbers separated by space... "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;

    int result = std::min(a, std::min(b, c));

    cout<<" minimum number is " << result<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Much pain, it will prevent. More productivity, it will produce.

;)